# How to put the url path to the specific files in server using JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I want to send the link which contains a path to the any file that is located in Server whenever user clicks the button. How can I do this in JSP?

For example, my file is stored in web-inf/temp0001111/JspContext.pdf.

So, whenever user click this link, then this file get downloaded into browser and allow the user to save.and also need to specify the life time of this link is to only 3 days.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the path under WEB-INF is not publicly visible so user can't simply `GET` it, you need to write a custom servlet which serve your purpose

Comment: Jigar: thanks,can u simply expalin about that custom Serlvet?